# mysql: getting ERROR 1054 when using INSERT INTO... SET to populate table

Tags: mysql, insert-into

tryin go to create a blog using the tutorials of phpacademy, I ran under a problem when it came to add a category name in my mysql using php (in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBcXMVjk83Q)

The author is using this code to put the name of the category into the categories table:

```
function add_category($name) {
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES `name` = `{$name}`");
```

}

But it didn't work for me (I am testing it on debian squeeze with PHP Version 5.3.3-7 and Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49).

I am connecting to mysql and to the database correctly but we trying the query directly in mysql via the command line, I have the following error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'uncategorized' in 'field list'
```

I then noticed that using this query was working:

```
INSERT INTO categories(name)VALUES('uncategorized');
```

but I wanted to know if there was a way to use the same method as the author used and if it was better, more secure, quicker (or what so ever) than the option that I found to be working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use wrong quotes here:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES `name` = `{$name}`");
```

Use single quotes:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `categories` VALUES `name` = '{$name}'");
```

Single quotes frame data, while backticks `` ` `` are used to mark database elements - tables, columns, etc.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much! Is there a difference in performance, security or best practice between the `INSERT INTO `categories` SET `name` = '{$name}'` and the `INSERT INTO categories(name)VALUES('{$name}')`?

Comment: No difference in security and performance, but it is often more convenient to use `INSERT INTO field_list VALUES (values_list)` because you can automatically fill the lists from your arrays. But this depend on the issue. Sometimes ` SET ` is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO categories(name) VALUES('$name')");
```